# Searching a custom table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm currently building a site for a client and they want a search feature that will search all of the products they supply.

I have created a new table in the database called sc_products and then tried the below code in a wordpress template page but I don't appear to be getting anywhere. If anyone knows how I can get this working that would be awesome!

```
<?php
/* 

Template Name: myTemp

*/

function search_it() {
if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {

    global $wpdb;

    $address_table = $wpdb->prefix . "sc_products";
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT product FROM ' . $sc_products );
    foreach ( $myrows as $single_row ) {
         global $single_row;
    }
    $product = $single_row->product;
}
    return $product;
}
$city = search_it();
echo $city;

get_search_form();

?>
```

Comment: An explanation of what you want this code to do would be most helpful.  As it stands, we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: HI, I have a custom table in my wordpress install database called sc_products then in here there are 3 columns containing product data.

I need to create a search form that will search all the data in this table only then return the matched results below the form - if nothing is returned it would return a string with a link to a contact form.

Comment: OK, that's more useful.  What are the three columns in the table? (Otherwise, how do we know how to write the query to search)

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late reply. All three of the columns are text type columns called Product, Application, Sector

Comment: where is `$sc_products` defined in your code? It should be `$address_table`, right?

Comment: The variable should be called $sc_products not $address_table- apologies for the confusion. I'm getting no where with getting this to work for me

Comment: Are you sure your if statement returns true and as such is getting to your rows, for example if you do an echo "foo" straight after the if statement do you actually get that far?

Comment: Hi Peter, no that doesnt appear to bring back anything either. I've tried echoing out a string directly after the if statement but the page has now stopped working. I have a feeling i've made this far more confusing than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things going on here, let's see if we can work them out.

Here's your modified function which should perform a search, with comments throughout to help explain what's going on.

NOTES:
1. You declare `$address_table`, but then use `$sc_products`.  That can't be correct, as `$sc_products` is not defined.
2. This answer is based on the column names you provided in comments - IF they are not an exact match, you'll need to update them, INCLUDING matching case.  If it's not `Application`, but instead `application`, you'll need to make that change.

```
function search_it() {
// If this is a search, and the search variable is set
    if ( is_search() && isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        // Global in $wpdb so we can run a query
        global $wpdb;
        // Build the table name - glue the table prefix onto the front of the table name of "sc_products"
        $address_table = $wpdb->prefix . "sc_products";
        // Get the search term into a variable for convenience
        $search = $_GET['s'];
        // To use "LIKE" with the wildcards (%), we have to do some funny business:
        $search = "%{$search}%";
        // Build the where clause using $wpdb->prepare to prevent SQL injection attacks
        // Searching ALL THREE of our columns: Product, Application, Sector 
        $where = $wpdb->prepare( 'WHERE Product LIKE %s OR Application LIKE %s OR Sector LIKE %s', $search, $search, $search );
        // Execute the query with our WHERE clause
        // NOTE: Your code originally used "$sc_products", but that variable was not defined - so have replaced to the proper $address_table here.
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT product FROM {$address_table} {$where}" );
        // return the results.  No need to put into an array, it's already an array
        return $product;
    }

    // For consistency, return an empty array if not a search / no search term
    return array();
}

// USAGE:
// Run the query
$cities = search_it();
// You can't echo an array!
// echo $city;
// var_dump to see the whole array
var_dump( $cities );

// More useful USAGE:
$cities = search_it();
// If there's any results
if ( ! empty( $cities ) ) {
    // Output a title
    echo '<h1>Product Search Results:</h1>';
    // Loop over the results
    foreach( $cities AS $city ) {
        // $wpdb returns an array of objects, so output the object properties
        echo '<h2>' . $city->Product . '</h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $city->Application . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $city->Sector . '</p>';
    }
}

get_search_form();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Cale, this doesn't appear to have worked nor does it output anything - it simply redirects to '/?s=searchterm' which is using my archive template. I feel like i've still not set something up or am missing a step. The table name is correct and the table headers are correct with the capital at the start so unsure whats happening.

Comment: Where do you have the function? Where do you have the "Usage" code? (Which file / template?)

Comment: I've created a new template file called page-search.php this is where this code then sits and is supposed to run. I've the created a page called product search in WordPress to display the search bar.

Comment: You need to work on the `search.php` template.  `page-search.php` will NOT display WP search results, only (AFAIK) the `search.php` template.